# Yii cgridview using dynamic active record model

Tags: yii, cgridview

I'm using the [Yii-dynamic-active-record](http://github.com/pavlepredic/Yii-dynamic-active-record) model class to get and put data to various database tables. Now I'd like to use cgridview to quickly build some views of this data, but I'm getting hung-up on writing a search function for this class.

I know that I could always do a foreach loop within the view and make my own html table, but if I could get the Yii way working that would be great for DRY.

*All the db tables have a ID column and this is the only column that really needs to be displayed... if you could get all the columns that would just be bonus points.

Thanks :)

Model

```
public function search()
{
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->compare('ID',$this->ID);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```

View

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'entry-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
    'ID',
),
));
```

Controller

```
$tablename=$_GET['tname'];
$table=Entry::forTable($tablename);
$model=$table->findAll();
if(isset($_GET['Entry']))
    $model->attributes=$_GET['Entry'];

$this->render('all',array(
    'model'=>$model,
));
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused by what you have done here, however I think I have a solution. First off, in line 3 of your controller code, you call `$model = $table->findAll();` this is likely not what you intended, as it will provide you with an `ActiveRecord[]`. What you want to do is to pass your `$table` into the gridview. So your controller code would look like this:

```
$tablename=$_GET['tname'];
$model=Entry::forTable($tablename);
if(isset($_GET['Entry']))
    $model->attributes=$_GET['Entry'];

$this->render('all',array(
    'model'=>$model,
));
```

you then need to pass in the table name to the `CActiveDataProvider` in your model:

```
public function search()
{
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->compare('ID',$this->ID);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this->tableName(), array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```

now for the "yucky" part, you need to edit the static model method of `CActiveRecord` to this:

```
if(isset(self::$_models[$className]))
return self::$_models[$className];
else
{
   if(class_exists($className)){
      $model=self::$_models[$className]=new $className(null);
      $model->_md=new CActiveRecordMetaData($model);
      $model->attachBehaviors($model->behaviors());
   }
   else{
      $model = Entry::forTable($className);
    }
    return $model;
}
```

This tells it to load from the Entry table when a class of that name does not exist. This practice is discouraged, however its the only way I see of getting around your issue.

Comment: The model file "Entry.php" is the dynamic active record, and the search function above is inside that class. I think there is some magic Yii stuff that goes on inside the cgridview that assumes that the model class name is the db table (or perhaps it's the $this in search function), I am unsure how to over-ride this. For your example above I get an Error 500 saying that there is no Entry table found in the db.

Comment: I edited my answer with a solution that works, however its a bit "yucky".

Comment: I've tried your solution three times but I keep getting an Error 500 saying: include(my_first_table.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: include(first_form.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory (/vendor/yiisoft/yii/framework/YiiBase.php:421)

Comment: I'm going to need the full stack trace to find the problem, Yii should output an error page with all the calls made from source to problem, if it does not do this, try enabling debug mode.